# Responsive CSS with Flex Box

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I'm working on a page that utilized FlexBox for it's tabber functionality. But since adding the tabber, my page seems to want to drop each side (profile) and (tabber) onto a new line, rather than scale the `<div>`'s size. As of right now, it's set to it's first media query around `1000px`. But this is much too large to swap it into a single column layout and would like to shrink them a little before dropping to new lines.

Here is the container, left side-div (profile), and right side-div (tabber)'s CSS:

```
.bio-pages .master-bio-container{
    max-width: 1090px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.professor__profile{
background: #FFF;
    display: Block;
    border-radius: 6px;
    float: left;
    max-width: 22rem;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 48px 15px;
    border-bottom: #BBB 3px solid
}

.tabs__body {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 260px;
      max-height: 410px;
    overflow: auto;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
}

.professor__tabs {
background-color: white;
    max-width: 44rem;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
        margin: 0 0 45px;
        border-radius:6px;
        border-bottom: #BBB 3px solid
}


@media (min-width: 40rem) {
  .professor__tabs {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
        -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

**[Here is my fiddle, please ignore the server side language](https://jsfiddle.net/8we805dg/)**

Any ideas on what could be causing this? Is this how FlexBox works?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have to reset the `width` and `float` (and maybe more of the properties, like margin etc) as well in your media query, or else it will mess up everything

Comment: When I scale down, the width and float seem to carry over fine, as in, they aren't crossed out in Inspect Element.

Comment: if you used flex, start from the main container to make it easier: example https://jsfiddle.net/8we805dg/1/

Comment: Making some fixes, but this definitely helped me get on the right track, thanks so much @GCyrillus!

Answer (score 0):

The `master-bio-container` `div` contains both children you wish to be columnar. The child <-> parent relationship with direct flex children is implicit.

```
.master-bio-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nf13qx42/